# Безопасность замены прав libvirt пула

Tags: python, linux, безопасность, kvm

Я пишу python пакет, который должен загружать файлы в `/var/lib/libvirt/images/newpool`. Однако без root прав нельзя писать в свежесозданный libvirt пул. Очевидное решение разрешить запись всем с помощью `chmod`, но будет ли это корректно с точки зрения безопасности? Есть ли другие способы решить данную проблему?

Comment: логичнее всего действовать через api. гугль подсказывает, что для php есть функция [libvirt_image_create()](https://libvirt.org/php/api-reference.html#libvirt_image_create). что-то аналогичное должно, по идее, быть и для python-а.

Comment: Есть api для python, однако через него нельзя загружать образы через ftp или http/https в пул. Подразумевается что это нужно делать средствами ОС.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пул в либвирт можно создавать в любом каталоге. У меня одинн создан в `/home/eri/Загрузки/`

Вам нужно попросить у пользователя доступ к подключению к либвирт.

Например если вызвать в консоли

```
virsh connect lxc:///
```

у пользователя на экране появится запрос привелегий через полкит. Окно если в иксах.
При запуске из питона этот запрос также выводится в окошко агента polkit.

```
import libvirt
conn = libvirt.open('qemu:///system')
```

дальше

```
conn.storagePoolCreateXML('''xml описание пула''')
```

И подсовывайте папку пользователя.

Консольный полкит агент (для сессий без иксов) обычно не запущен, но можно его запустить `pkttyagent` принудительно. Тут конечно интересный вопрос...

Или можно попросить у пользователя запускать Ваш скрипт через sudo.

А ещё можно добавить пользователя в группу `libvirt` тогда запросов не будет - лучший вариант как мне кажется.